# Free Proxy Servers for Windows OS?

Tags: windows, proxy

pretty simple question: anyone know of any free proxy servers for windows? I'm currently using squid (which is great, btw) but it doesn't handle http 1.1.

So, anyone know of any other suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try [FreeProxy](http://www.handcraftedsoftware.org/index.php?page=5)? The feature list includes HTTP 1.1 connections. Here is a summary from the Handcreaftedsoftware's website:

- Internet connection sharing with demand dialling
- HTTP proxy, including FTP over HTTP
- SOCKS5
- SMTP & POP email proxy
- NNTP proxy
- Outlook Express / Hotmail email proxy
- TCP tunnel (tunnel any TCP protocol)
- HTTP cache
- Connect to ICQ and MSN easily
- HTTP 1.1 persistent connections, RFC2616 and RFC2518 compliant. See Compliancy below.
- Demand Dialling, auto connect/disconnect
- URL filtering has been replaced by Resource Security which allows username password authentication and access to
- resources.
- URL and IP address filtering from imported Ban Lists
- Remote access to display statistics of users
- Access controlled by user and calendar
- Resources include IP addresses, ports, URLs, paths, IP services
- Comprehensive access logs which are user configurable
- Create users and groups and/or authenticate to a Windows domain
- Built-in web server
- Run as a service under Win NT/2000/XP/2003 or Win98/Me
- Message logging and dumping
- Connect to another Proxy server or connect directly to the internet
- Bind to a specific network interface for added security ("local binding")
- Works with Dial-up Networking and Cable/Broadband

Comment: +1 - I have done some crazy things with FreeProxy back in the day

Comment: can confirm it works with windows 2008 standard edition. I've made the proxy cache save to a USB drive/disk :)

Comment: The link is dead.  Download is [here](http://www.handcraftedsoftware.org/index.php?page=download&op=getFile&id=2&title=FreeProxy-Internet-Suite)

Answer (score 1):

[3proxy](http://3proxy.ru/) looks promising.  Supports HTTP1.1 according to the release notes.