# How to setup a proxy server on my LAN?

Tags: local-area-network, proxy

Here is my network configuration: My computer is inside a LAN. All the internet traffic goes through a default gateway. I wish to conduct an experiment. I want to monitor user traffic pattern. I want to setup a proxy server to which other users will connect to for accessing the internet. I wish to log the URLs that they visited and forward their traffic to the gateway. Is there a tool which will help me do this?

Comment: Yes there is a tool. It is called HTTP Proxy. Use a product of your choice which claims to be a HTTP Proxy.

Comment: @All: Is there a free HTTP proxy for Windows which has no restrictions on the number of users allowed to connect to it?

Comment: Look closer! Even here is a search box in the upper right corner. http://serverfault.com/questions/4523/free-proxy-servers-for-windows-os

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much any proxy/gateway will do this. Squid is a good one. PFSense is a good complete solution if you don't feel like doing much work yourself. You can install PFSense on a server (a virtual server is OK), and then install the Squid plugin for it.

Then, you point all your computers to the squid/PFSense machine as their gateway, and your current gateway becomes the gateway of the squid/PFSense machine.

So it goes:

`Computer > Squid/PFSense > Gateway`

Voila.